# Remove all <a href="www.example.com" > </a> tags from an html string

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to remove all the `<a href=""> </a>` tags from an html string using regex in Java but it doesn't seem to be working. Any pointers would help.

I tried:

```
replaceAll( "<a\b[^>]+>([^<]*(?:(?!</a)<[^<]*)*)</a>", ""); 
replaceAll("<a.*?>|</a>","");
```

and a couple of other options read from SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you calling `replaceAll`? You need to assign the result back to a variable. It doesn't modify strings in place.

```
str = str.replaceAll("...");
```

Comment: OK John. i did a blunder..would be more helpful if you could help me with the two regex i posted above...

Comment: think the .*? means . -any character * -any number of times ? - not at all.